# use Firestore model value as toggle to present fullscreen view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have two screens in a SwiftUI app.
Screen A is displayed after the app launch and contains a button which will update the value for `currentWorkoutID` on the `user` model and save that modification to a Firestore database.

Screen B is shown from screen A when `currentWorkoutID` is not nil on the `user` model.

The problem that I'm seeing is that when I press the button in screen A, screen B immediately shows up (no animation), then is dismissed with animation and then is shown again with no animation.

I'm unsure what the issue is or how to solve it.

```
struct TrainingProgramDetails: View{
    @EnvironmentObject var workoutCompletionStore: WorkoutCompletionDataStore
    var presentWorkoutScreenBinding: Binding<Bool> {
        Binding(get: {
            return userDataStore.user.profileData.currentWorkoutID != nil
        },
                set: { value in
            //nothing to do here
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        let nextWorkoutID = userDataStore.user.profileData.currentWorkoutID 

        GeometryReader { screenGeometryProxy in
            let imageHeight = screenGeometryProxy.size.height / 3
            WorkoutsList(workouts: program.workoutsData) {
                ...
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: presentWorkoutScreenBinding,
                             onDismiss: {
                             }, content: {
                                 WorkoutScreenAdaptor(workoutID: nextWorkoutID!,
                                                      onShowFeedback: showFeedback)
                             })
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
}
```

```
struct User: Codable {
    var profileData: ProfileData = .init()
    ...
}

struct ProfileData: Codable {
    var currentWorkoutID:String?
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was on a container to this screen that would cause this screen to be taken out of view and then reloaded.